Definition for 2d image alignment
I am currently working on paper for image alignment with machine learning. Therefore, I want to provide a more abstract definition and I am not sure if I am missing something or I am on the wrong track.

Consider a manifold $(M, \cal T)$ with $n$-dimensions with two image dimensions, one temporal dimension and a $k$ latent dimension. An image is represented by an open set $U \in \cal T$, where all open sets $U$ overlap in the latent dimensions and are disjoint in the temporal dimension. Each open set has a corresponding chart $(h, U)$ with $h: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. We also have a similarity measure $s: (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that compares two images in an Euclidean space.
Given two open sets $U_0$ and $U_1$ representing images with their respective charts, we can define a transition function $t: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ using the mappings in the charts. Specifically, the transition function is $t_{01} := h_1 \circ h^{-1}_0$, which maps the image to the manifold and then to the space of the other image.
With that, we can check the alignment of two images using a similarity measure after transforming $h_0(U)$ to the space of $h_1(U_1)$ with $(t_{01} \circ h_0)(U)$. The alignment quality depends on the function's properties $h_i$ and the constructed manifold in the latent dimensions.

This definition should allow me to add constraints to the mapping $h$ like being $C^d$ differentiable and make the manifolds structure in the latent dimensions arbitrary with respect to the constraints?
